# quicker way to specify nested elements in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$(this).parent().children('.vote_count').children('span.number')
```

but I am wondering if there is a better way to go up one level, down two from a selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense it some:

```
$(this).parent().find('> .vote_count > span.number')
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/esowe)

This has the advantage of offloading as much as possible to the selector engine (rather than making individual function calls), where it can *possibly* be optimized. (It won't necessarily be, just that you're making it possible.) Unlike several of the other solutions here, it won't miss out the current element if it's a `.vote-count`, it respects your use of immediate-child functions rather than descendant functions, and moreover it's simple. Your original seemed just fine to me as well, though.

Your original only considers immediate children, which I assume was intentional, but just for completeness, I'll mention:

If you want to find `.vote-count` at *any* level under the parent, and look for immediate children of them that are `span.number`, do this instead:

```
// Slightly different from your original, see comment above
$(this).parent().find('.vote_count > span.number')
```

If you only want to find `.vote-count`s that are *immediate* children, but then find `span.number` underneath them wherever they are (even if not immediate children), do this:

```
// Slightly different from your original, see comment above
$(this).parent().find('> .vote_count span.number')
```

...and finally if you want find any `.vote-count` anywhere under the parent (not just as an immediate child) and find any `span.number` under it (not just as an immediate child):

```
// Fairly different from your original, see comment above
$(this).parent().find('.vote_count span.number')
```

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
$("> .vote_count > span.number", $(this).parent())
```

or

```
$("> span.number", $(this).siblings(".vote_count"))
```

or

```
$("~ .vote_count > span.number", this)
```

or

```
$(this).find("~ .vote_count > span.number")`
```

using the [sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) and the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: nice one. Will accept answer once it lets me. Not sure why I have to wait!!

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: Note that these are *not* the same as your original. These use *descendant* selectors, not immediate child selectors.

Comment: @TJ good point, thought it would be unlikely that there would be those children deeper in the hierarchy this is more concise.

Comment: @hunter: We have no idea whether it would be likely or not. Good edit to fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what OP meant by *"quicker"*, but it's worth noting that specifying a context is slower (execution).

Comment: @TJ I would be mad at my designer/developer if he/she were css class-ing elements like that. ;)

Comment: This should work fine, but I would suggest using the .find() method instead of .children; it has a bit better performance and does the same thing.

Comment: if "quicker" means "faster", then those selectors are definetly slower.

Comment: @RussellUresti: actually `.children()` should have a slightly better performance than `.find()` since it only grabs immediate child elements.

Comment: check out the last one, I dig that greatly

Comment: @hunter: The last one (currently `$(this).find("~ .vote_count > span.number")` as I write this) is **again** using a descendant selector where the OP used an immediate-child function. It will find *any* `.vote-count` element at any level that's a descendant (not child) of a sibling. Also, note that the OP didn't say that `this` couldn't be a `.vote-count`, but it will be omitted if you use a sibling selector (the same problem patrick w pointed out about Matt Ball's answer).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: it also implies the use of the universal selector `*`, which should perform pretty poorly also.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : http://jsperf.com/parent-children-vs-sibling Ignore the title, I changed what it to test children vs find.

Comment: could I ask for a bit of description with each one, would make this question better reference for others.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - The last two that use `~` don't seem to work at all. Not for me anyway. [Here's your code](http://jsbin.com/upopu4/) compared to [the last solution](http://jsbin.com/upopu4/2/). The first two examples take a context as the second argument, which is a slower equivalent of `$(this).parent().find("> .vote_count > span.number")` (for the first example). You'd be better off with your original code.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)?

```
$(this).siblings('.vote_count').children('span.number');
```

After all, the children of my parents are my siblings.

---

*Edit* as per @patrick dw's comment, if you need to ensure that `this` is also included* then you can use [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf):

```
$(this).siblings('.vote_count').andSelf().children('span.number');
```

---

After a bit of discussion with patrick (see comments), it looks like the best answer is likely the one you already have: `$(this).parent().children('.vote_count').children('span.number')`, unless you can make assumptions about `this` based on how you selected it.

---

<sup>*The first answer (the one that doesn't use `andSelf()`) assumes that `this` is not a `.vote_count`.</sup>

Comment: It could be a problem if `this` is also a `.vote_count` element. In that case it would be excluded. Not sure if that's the situation here, though.

Comment: @patrick: `this` will be excluded no matter what - but I get what you mean. Editing accordingly.

Comment: Matt - In the question, `this` would not be excluded if `this` is a `.vote_count` element, because `.parent().children('.vote_count')` will include `this` in the elements being filtered, whereas `.siblings('.vote_count')` wouldn't.

Comment: @patrick - yes yes yes. When I said "`this` will be excluded no matter what" I meant in _my_ answer. Anyway, `andSelf()` to the rescue!

Comment: ...regarding your edit, the trouble with `.andSelf()` is that you're calling it *after* `.siblings('.vote_count')`, which means it will be added even if it isn't a `.vote_count`. You would need something like `$(this).siblings().andSelf().filter('.vote_count')...`.

Comment: @patrick: blarg. You're right. I have no idea how `this` is being selected... so the best answer may actually be the one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you're fine sticking with your original version, although I might change it to eliminate the `.parent()` call by using the native `.parentNode` property.

```
$(this.parentNode).children('.vote_count').children('span.number')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find(".vote_count > span.number");
```

is one alternative.

Comment: That uses a descendant selector for the `.vote-count` part. The OP used an immediate-child selector.

Comment: Yup, totally right. I hadn't realised find() would accept a leading combinator (e.g. ">") but I'm glad I learnt that today!

Answer (score 0):

I'll not quite sure if this what you are looking for:

```
$(this).parent().find('.vote_count > span.number')
```

Comment: Note that that's not the same as the original. The original only deals with immediate children, yours is using descendant selectors instead.